# Why does this reverse list python code return the reversed list?

Tags: python

```
def reverseList(self, head):
    cur, prev = head, None
    while cur:
        cur.next, prev, cur = prev, cur, cur.next
    return prev
```

This is the python code which return the reverse order linked list like below.

Input: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> Null

Output: 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> Null

The question is when I hand write the output with input, it comes out below process.

```
    At the first while loop
cur.next = N,
prev = 1,
cur = 2
    At the Second while loop
cur.next = 1,
prev = 2,
cur = 3
    At the third while loop
cur.next = 2,
prev = 3,
cur = N

return 3
```

I guess it should return only 3, not 3 -> 2 -> 1-> Null. Why this code return the reverse order Linked list? Could anyone answer?

Comment: You're conflating nodes with the data they hold. If `cur` is a node (with a `.next` attribute) then `cur.data` might be `2`, but `cur` itself is not `2` since there is no such thing as `2.next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already wrote the answer yourself:

```
cur = 3
    At the third while loop
cur.next = 2,
```

Comment: Does this mean it can return the reverse ordered Linked list?

Comment: @Hume Well yeah, you return the 3-node, which now points to the 2-node (due to the part I pointed out), which now points to the 1-node. That's the reversed list.

Comment: At the third while loop, cur.next = 2, prev = 3, cur = N. Which part is pointing 2-node and 1-node?